# postman: Is there any way to figure out the data file type/name during execution?

Tags: postman

I need to create pre-request scripts that adapt behavior based on whether data is sourced via json or csv files.

Is there any runtime mechanism to determine the data file type or the name of the data file?

Something that helps me do the following,

```
if (data.fileType === "json") {
 //data interpretation as per json hierarchy
} else {
 //data interpretation as per csv structure
}
```

Here, what can I use to replace `data.fileType`?

Or is it possible to figure out `data.fileName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try parsing `data` as json.

```
var parsedData;

try {
   parsedData = JSON.parse(data); // Will throw an error if data not JSON
   // Your logic to parse data as JSON goes here
} catch (e) {
   parsedData = data; // data is not JSON, check for CSV
   // Your logic to parse as CSV goes here
}
```